# How to become a linux device driver programmer?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

Can any one suggest me how to become a linux device driver programmer.
I have many doubts as I am working as software engineer in a company (1+ yr experience ).Our project is done using C,c++ in linux and windows both,I am working in C,C++ and using Visual studio and Linux GCC for my project.Our project is mainly on remote management of servers and systems.

I am very interested linux kernel-device driver programming .
can any one tell me what is good for me,and how to start I got some books (LDD 3ed ,etc ) but only reading book is sufficient or I have to get some training.

what about this driver programming future and scope.
Kindly tell some suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: Programmers.SE seems to have an answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/52729

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LDD O'Reilly book is really good (Rubini et all), Also take a look at the LXR project:

http://lxr.linux.no/

It is a great cross-linked reference of the kernel source. Reading over current driver code is probably the best way to become acquainted.

The best way to learn any language or coding style is to read as much code as you can. Compile it, modify it, crash the kernel, and just play around. Kernel drivers are my personal favorite thing to write, you have a lot of exciting stuff to see!

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I am very interested in this area ,I also want to be a good device driver developer.